# Efficient way to search single record from 6000k+ record DB in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to know how to search a single record from a *6000k+* record database. I have written a query for it but I am facing `15s` load time it's too high for the efficient system so please help me to search in an efficient way to take lower response time in searching.

```
$users = DB::select('select * from tablefour where Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Fax_Number = ?', array($request['id'])); 
return $users;
```

Comment: Have you created an index for ```Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Fax_Number``` column?

Comment: welcome to SO. here is my opinion, there are several way to query optimisation in database, in your situation database is more responsible than PHP or Laravel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Make the column index then search will work fast on that column.This help me.

**For Laravel:-**
Do this in Schema

```
    final class AddIndexesTableFour extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('tablefour', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->index('Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Telephone_Number');
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('tablefour', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropIndex(['Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Telephone_Number']);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1st** Only select those columns which you needed.

```
$users = \DB::table('tablefour')->select(['columnone','columntwo'])->whereIn('Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Fax_Number',array($request['id']))->get();
return $users;
```

**2nd**

Make `indexing` on those columns in which columns are you selecting.

Check @Rana Nadeem answer for how to make indexing.

using migration

```
Schema::table('tablefour', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('user_id');
});
```